# Get a List With `Partition`

Tags: partitions

How can I add two brackets for a sublists of Length 2 ?

Objective:

> {{{1, 2}}, {{3, 4}}, {{5, 6}}, {{7, 8}}, {{9, 10}}, {{11, 12}}, {{13, 
>   14}}, {{15, 16}}, {{17, 18}}}

*The code I write here only give only 1 bracket for  a sublist of length 2*

Input:

> Partition[Table[i, {i, 18}], 2]

Output:

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}, {13, 14}, {15, 
>   16}, {17, 18}}
> ```

Comment: Try `Map[{#} &, Partition[Table[i, {i, 18}], 2]]`

Comment: Thanks.  Any other way to work it out?@UlrichNeumann

Comment: `ArrayReshape[Table[i, {i, 18}], {9, 1, 2}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, Great work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$HistoryLength = 0;
```

The two methods produce identical results

```
With[{n = 1000},
 List /@ Partition[Range[n], 2] ===
  ArrayReshape[Range[n], {n/2, 1, 2}]]

(* True *)
```

Comparing timings

```
timing1[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 RepeatedTiming[List /@ Partition[Range[n], 2];][[1]]

timing2[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{data = Range[n]},
  RepeatedTiming[ArrayReshape[data, {Length[data]/2, 1, 2}];][[1]]]

ListLogLogPlot[{
  {#, timing1[#]} & /@ (10^Range[7]),
  {#, timing2[#]} & /@ (10^Range[7])},
 Joined -> True,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"number of elements", 
     "timing"}),
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[{"Partition and Map", ArrayReshape}, {.35, .75}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Slower than `ArrayReshape`  but ... there is also

[`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html)

```
BlockMap[List, Range@18, 2]
```

> {{{1, 2}}, {{3, 4}}, {{5, 6}}, {{7, 8}}, {{9, 10}}, {{11, 12}}, {{13, 
>          14}}, {{15, 16}}, {{17, 18}}}

and the (undocumented) 6-argument form of `Partition`:

```
Partition[Range@18, 2, 2, 1, {}, {{##}} &]
```

> {{{1, 2}}, {{3, 4}}, {{5, 6}}, {{7, 8}}, {{9, 10}}, {{11, 12}}, {{13, 
>          14}}, {{15, 16}}, {{17, 18}}}

Answer (score 4):

Trying with patterns is very easy in order to handle all that stuff.

If you have defined `list = Partition[Table[i, {i, 19}], UpTo[2]]` , you could obtain your preferred result in two different ways :

First :

```
list /. (a_List)?(Length[#] == 2 &) :> {a}
```

Second and much simpler :

```
Partition[Table[i, {i, 18}], 2] /. {a_, b_} :> {{a, b}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Possibly what you are looking for:

```
First @ Partition[{Range[18]}, {1, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}}, {{3, 4}}, {{5, 6}}, {{7, 8}}, {{9, 10}},
>    {{11, 12}}, {{13, 14}}, {{15, 16}}, {{17, 18}}}
> ```

Note the extra `{ }` around `Range[18]` to make it two dimensional.

Or Partitioning sequentially:

```
Fold[Partition, Range[18], {2, 1}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) and [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) with [`TwoWayRule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TwoWayRule.html).

```
Transpose[{Partition[Range@18, {2}]}, 2 <-> 1]
```

> ```
> {{{1,2}},{{3,4}},{{5,6}},{{7,8}},{{9,10}},{{11,12}},{{13,14}},{{15,16}},{{17,18}}}
> ```

`TwoWayRule` was introduced in version 11.2 so if you have an earlier version than the following is equivalent.

```
Transpose[{Partition[Range@18, {2}]}, {2, 1, 3}]
```

Hope this helps.